# Is Window Forms Application created with Visual C++ 2005 will run without .netFramework on other computers

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

> Is Windows Forms Application created with Visual C++ 2005 will run
>   without .netFramework on other
>   computers
>
> and how i can check that application
>   on my computer that it will rum on
>   other computers without .net Framework

Answer (score 1):

No. You could use a bootstrapper like [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) to check and install .NET Framework before the setup of your application is installed.

I do this for a number of applications successfully.

Comment: so what tool or language feature in visual studio 2005 i can use to create  non .netFramework dependent application

Comment: MFC for example. Or plain Win32.